# Maximum data received using BulkTransfer API call

Tags: android, kotlin, usb, transfer, bulk

I am working on bulkTransfer API in Android. I can able to receive 32768 bytes from the Bulkin endpoint during video streaming. But, if I set the buffer length higher than 32768, USB data is not getting. Instead, I am receiving -1 as a return.

Here, Android acts as a Host, and CX3 is the Device.

My questions are :

> 1. How to ensure full buffer data is received?
> 2. Using BulkTransfer API call, how much data we can receive?

Our analysis is,

> Buffer data in CX3 is 512 Kbytes
>
> Currently we are receiving 32768 bytes only out of 512 Kbytes using bulkTransfer API

From this link, we understood https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection

> the length of the data to send or receive. Before 28, a value larger than 16384 bytes would be truncated down to 16384. In API 28 and after, any value of length is valid.

Limitations we found are

> Data type for the buffer is Integer. In Kotlin, Integer takes 4 bytes. Maximum 4,294,967,296 bytes.

why can't we able to receive full buffer data in one go?

My code snippet is kotlin:

```
                    val bytes_stream = ByteArray(32768)

                    val result = connection?.bulkTransfer(
                        endpoint_in,                        //BULK IN Endpoint
                        bytes_stream,                       //Buffer data
                        bytes_stream.size,                  //Buffer length
                        TIMEOUT                             //infinite waiting time 
                    ) 

                    if (result != -1) {
                        Log.d("", Arrays.toString(bytes_stream))
                    }
```